# Mule ESB 3.4 Context property

Tags: spring, properties, mule, esb

How can one access the properties loaded by `context:place-holder` in a scripting component other than having to use `${property-name}`? I want to get to the object that holds these key value pairs. Something like `context.getProperty("property-name")`.

Answer (score 5):

Spring property placeholders are resolved at configuration time and not stored anywhere, so they cant be loaded afterwards.

If you need to store it you can always inject them into a bean and retrieve that from the registry.

Basically all you need to do is to declare your bean:

```
<spring:bean class="your.Bean" name="yourBean" >
   <spring:property name="yourBeanAttribute" value="${somePlaceHolder}" />
</spring:bean>
```

and then you can retrieve it, and the somePlaceHolder value from the registry from within a scripting component/transformer:

```
<scripting:transformer doc:name="Script">
 <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
  <scripting:text><![CDATA[
def val = muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObject('yourBean').getYourBeanAttribute()
]]></scripting:text>
  </scripting:script>
 </scripting:transformer>
```

HTH

Comment: Is it possible for you to show an example of the bean/registry idea?